# How to show loading icon after submiting the form but not in case the Model is not valid in ASP .NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I want to show a loading-icon after submitting the form, but not if the View Model is not valid (I mean jQuery MVC validation).

```
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register"/>
        <div class="work-con"></div>
```

If I use something like this

```
    $("#myform").submit(function (event) {
        // Animate loader
        $(".work-con").fadeIn("slow");
    });
```

it works fine, but it shows the icon even if the Model is not valid and the warnings are displayed.

Comment: Use `fadeOut` on the element when the validation logic fails.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

MVC uses jQuery validation. You can use that to check if the form is valid:

```
$("#myform").submit(function (event) {

    var isValid = $('#myForm').valid();
    if (isValid) {    
        // Animate loader
        $(".work-con").fadeIn("slow");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Thats it. I didn't know the valid() method.

Answer (score 0):

Though question already answer. But also may alternative/help for when valid function not working due to jquery version conflict

Add a div before submit button or the place where icon you want to show

```
<div class="loading" style="display: none;"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Progressing …</div>
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#sendbtn").click(function(){  // your submit button id
      var isValid = document.querySelector('#myform')
      if (isValid.checkValidity())
        $(".loading").show();
   });
});
```